# How to change function name and variable name of class in typescript when build using webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I want to rename all variable and function of class typescript when build using webpack. Example:

```
class Game {
  private test: string;
  init() {

  }
  delete(){
  }
}
```

How to build test -> a, init ->b , delete ->c. Thanks

Comment: FWIW, I did some quick web searching and found some webpack plugins ([1](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/webpack-obfuscator), [2](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin)) that are supposed to be able to obfuscate variable names, but not property names.  I suspect this is because it's hard to know what property names might be referenced externally (meaning that obfuscating them would break the code).

Comment: I don't think this is a TS problem, but rather a JS problem. TS gets compiled to JS, JS gets uglified/obfuscated. What's your goal here? Do you want to make the end result smaller in file size? That's usually called uglifying or minification. Do you want to make it hard for someone to read the end result? That's usually called obfuscation. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/obfuscator-loader